# Obj-C Error: Expected expression before ...... (why?)

Tags: c, objective-c, enums, typedef

Hi I have an enum declared like this:

```
typedef enum {
    Top,             
    Bottom,
    Center
} UIItemAlignment;
```

In my code I try to use it like this:

```
item.alignment = UIItemAlignment.Top;
```

I get an error like this: " Expected expression before 'UIItemAlignment' "

If I use only:

```
item.alignment = Top;
```

everything works fine but why do I get this error if I try to use it the other way?

`_alignment` is an `NSInteger` and it has a property declared like this

`@property (readwrite) NSInteger alignment;` and I synthesized it in my implementation file.

So my question is, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enum values are not specified via their type in objective-c nor c++.  The syntax you are trying to use is how C# handles it though.

Comment: A couple of additional thoughts: Consider using the type as a prefix for the enum values, e.g. ItemAlignmentTop, ItemAlignmentCenter, etc. Note that it's best to avoid using UI as a prefix, because that's what Apple uses as a prefix for everything in UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

To specify an enumeration value you do not need to specify its type. To be more clear you could write something like this:

```
UIItemAlignment alignment = Top;
item.alignment = alignment;
```

But it is not necessary to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The values declared inside `enum { }` are integer constants in their own right and not tied to the enumeration type. They are used as `int` values similar to `#define`'d constants. Additionally you may choose to use the enum type (e.g. `UIItemAlignment` here) as a type of integer variable that is guaranteed to be able to represent the enumeration constants, but the type itself is not a class or a structure containing those constants - hence the `.` does not work.